# Aligning data in a single column to the right in a python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently have a dataframe in Python and now I am trying to align one column to the right because when I export it to the excel it is currently aligning to the left.

| Name | Area | Location Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1234 |  |
| green | 4567 | 30.23mph |
| blue | 8901 |  |

the column that I am currently trying to move, in this case, is Location Type and it has both numbers, letters, and some rows blank.

I tried using this line of code:

```
df = df.style.set_properties(subset=["Location Type"], **{'text-align': 'right'})
```

I tried testing it out on the other columns to see if there was something wrong with the column but I received this error for both.

```
ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to align to the right so what I noticed was that excel aligns numbers to the right.

I removed any string characters and converted the column to float by using the following two lines.

```
df['Location Type'] = df['Location Type'].str.extract('(\d+\.*\d*)', expand=False)
df['Location Type'] = df['Location Type'].astype(float)
```